# Accessing url with model and view on Spring Boot project

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Hi a Java newbie here.

I am trying to send a URL via modelAndView to an html page that is using thymeleaf.

My controller looks something like this.

```
@RequestMapping("/api/test")
public ModelAndView test(){
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    String google = "www.google.com";
    modelAndView.addObject("google", google);
    modelAndView.setViewName("api/googleTest");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

And my the button where I am using this attribute looks something like this

```
<button class="w-100 btn btn-secondary btn-lg" type="button"
                th:onclick="|location.href='@{{link}(link=${google})}'|">
```

And when I push the button, my application seems to redirect to http://localhost:8080/api/www.google.com instead of [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

It would be sincerely appreciated if there would be a way to fix this problem.
Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens when you add "http://"?

Like `String google = "http://www.google.com";`

Answer (score 0):

You missed to setup the Path variable into your controller.

Go through with below URL

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-pathvariable

if still not clear ping me back.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.